# #define constexpr in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I came across some code as shown below:

```
#define set_opcode(name) \
    constexpr static auto get_opcode() noexcept \
    { \
        return OpcodeValue::name; \ //OpcodeValue is some enum
    }

class NoopOpcode : public Opcode
{
public:
    set_opcode(NOOP);

    std::string serialize() const noexcept override;

    bool deserialize(const std::string &serialized) noexcept override;

    void execute(state::State &state) const noexcept override;

};


class InvOpcode : public Opcode
{

private:

    Int _item_id{};

    Int _item_count{};



public:

    set_opcode(INV);

    std::string serialize() const noexcept override;

    bool deserialize(const std::string &serialized) noexcept override;

    void execute(state::State &state) const noexcept override;

};
```

what is the reason/benefit for using #define to declare a constexpr?

Isn't it same thing as explicitly declaring get_opcode() {return OpcodeValue::NOOP; } inside the class NoopOpcode for example?

Comment: The macro makes it convenient to create multiple variations of the constexpr function. I don't think there's a reason other than convenience.

Comment: Looks like someone just wanted to have the preprocessor create a function for them

Comment: If your enum has 256 opcodes then it saves a bunch of typing to define all of them.

Comment: I see, so basically you save duplicating same lines of code. My next question is if this is common practice in C++? I'm a noob in C++ so I have no idea...

Comment: I would prefer `class NoopOpcode : public OpcodeHelper<OpcodeValue::NOOP>` to factorize code.

Comment: Much of C++ templating is about trying to remove this sort of macro magic from C. It is not always possible, but you should try to avoid it where you can.